# Extending Django Admin from Third Party App

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add a small HTML snippet to the `admin/base.html` template from a third party app (as in pip installable).

Two things that worked so far:

- Write my own middleware that parses the generated template and adds the HTML.
- Ship the whole admin template with my app and put it before `django.contrib.admin` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Both solutions are a total overkill for what I want to do. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Django app with template in templates/admin/base.html must be upper django.contrib.admin

Example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'your_app_with_admin_base',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
]
```

Then django will use base.html from your app